# javascript pega variável em form php de forma errada.

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho esse script e esse form populado em php, gostaria de usar o botao apagar pra enviar o nome do treino a ser apagado. O problema é que o javascript sempre recebe o valor(nometreino) da primeira linha tabela, mesmo em outros botões. Quando uso o inspecionar na página carregada, cada botão está com seu valor correto, mas o valor é sempre o da primeira linhas. (sim estou usando algumas funções obsoletas do php, está não é a questão).

```js
$(function($) {
 // Quando o formulário for enviado, essa função é chamada
 $("#formulario").submit(function() {
  // Colocamos os valores de cada campo em uma váriavel para facilitar a manipulação
  var nometreino = $("#nometreino").val();
     var resposta = confirm("Deseja mesmo deletar? " +nometreino);
 
     if (resposta == true) {

  // Fazemos a requisão ajax com o arquivo envia.php e enviamos os valores de cada campo através do método POST
  $.post('cadastro/remover_treino.php', {nometreino: nometreino }, function(resposta) {
    // Quando terminada a requisição
    // Exibe a div status
    $("#status").slideDown();
    // Se a resposta é um erro
    if (resposta != false) {
     // Exibe o erro na div
     $("#status").html(resposta).fadeOut(4000);
                    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 3000);
    } 
    // Se resposta for false, ou seja, não ocorreu nenhum erro
    else {
     // Exibe mensagem de sucesso
     $("#status").html("Apagado! " +nometreino).fadeOut(3000);
                    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 3000);  
     // Limpando todos os campos
     $("#nometreino").val("");
     $("#mensagem").val("");
    }
  });
     }
 });
    
});
```

```html
body role="document">
      
       <form method="post">  
<div class=""><br>
<br>
    </div>
      </form>
       <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">      
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Gerenciar Treinos</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

          <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="">Selecione a matrícula:</label>
              <div class="">
                <div class=""> <i class=""></i>
                  <form action = "" method="post">
  <?php
  include 'sel_matricula_treinos.php';
  ?>
      
<button type="submit" onClick="" class="" >Selecionar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          
          
<p>&nbsp;</p>
            
<?php
      $matricula = @$_POST['matricula'];

  $resultado=mysql_query("SELECT distinct (nometreino), ativo, alteracao FROM treinos WHERE idmatricula='$matricula'");

?> 
 <form action="javascript:function()" method="post"  id="formulario"> 
     <center><div id="status"></div> </center>
     
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome do treino (<?php echo $matricula;?>)</th>
                <th>Data de cadastro</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Apagar</th>
                  

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php 
     while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        $ativo=$linhas['ativo'];
                        $nometreino=$linhas['nometreino'];
      echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>",$nometreino,"</td>";
                        
                        echo "<td>"; 
                             echo date_format(new DateTime($linhas['alteracao']), "d/m/Y");                                
                        echo "</td>";

                        echo "<td>"; if ($ativo == 1) { echo "Ativo";} 
                        else {echo "Inativo";}
                        
                        echo "<td>"; ?>
                
                 <input type="hidden" name="nometreino" id="nometreino" value="<?php echo $nometreino?>">
<input type="submit" value="Apagar">
                
                    <?php
                        echo $nometreino;
                        
                        echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }

    ?>
                       
            </tbody>
              
              
              
          </table>
</form>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: O javascript não está diretamente a receber valores do php, está a ir buscar ao html, que foi construído em php. E essa busca está a ser feita com `.val()`, aqui: `var nometreino = $("#nometreino").val();` quando esse `nometreino` vem de um `td` : `echo "<td>",$nometreino,"</td>";`, o que não está correto. Em vez disso use `.html()`. `.val()` é para ser utilizado em `<input>, <select> e <textarea>` [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: tem como mandar o codigo fonte? botão direito > exibir codigo fonte

Comment: o form de apagar tem que estar no loop, não vai funcionar vários botões e linhas dentro do mesmo formulário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML, substitua:

```
<input type="submit" value="Apagar">
```

Por

```
<button type="button" class="apagar" value="<?=$nometreino?>">Apagar<button>
```

No JavaScript, substitua:

```
// Quando o formulário for enviado, essa função é chamada
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
    // Colocamos os valores de cada campo em uma váriavel para facilitar a manipulação
    var nometreino = $("#nometreino").val();
```

Por:

```
// Quando a ação de apagar for executada.
$(".apagar").on("click", function(e){
// Recebe o identificador do treino especificamente.
var nometreino = $(e.target).val();
```

Se funcionar, me mande uma confirmação e se quiser eu te explico porque não estava funcionando antes blz?

Comment: Amigo, funcionou. Muito obrigado, de noite colo o código funcionando. O erro  estava acontecendo pois o java script pegava o valor antes de eu clicar, isto ?

Comment: O problema estava na chamada $("#nometreino").val();

Comment: Que está dentro de um loop, onde existem vários inputs com o mesmo id, então ele sempre seleciona o primeiro